# Downloaded aspx website does not display well

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have downloaded a aspx webpage and saved it as html. I open it in IE and chrome and it takes time to load + some parts are missing. All the text is there but the `onmouseover` is not working properly and some css is not displaying correctly. Was the content not downloaded completely? i.e is it missing sme javascript, css or else?

Comment: Perhaps look at the source and search for `<script` or `<style` to see what external files are referenced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done what you describe on many occasions for the purposes of putting together a prototype of new functionality in an existing application.

You will likely need to do a couple of things:

- Ensure the paths to your JS and CSS resources are right (removing the unneccessary JS files, if any)
- Also, you will likely need to update the paths in your CSS to any image resources in your page

Comment: `Ensure the paths to your JS and CSS resources are right` compared to what? If there match my local files? or compared to the original website? The orginal website. Sorry, I'm still a noob.

Comment: As Mike mentioned you need to make sure that the SRC and HREF attributes of your SCRIPT and LINK tags point to the downloaded JS and CSS files.

Then check your CSS files for any URL definitions and make sure those paths correctly point at the image files you expect to see.